# Delete Image after using Share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I am new to android programming.

I have made an app in which images can be shared on various apps. Everything works fine but after the image is shared the images are saved in the phone. The images are saved in different folders on different devices.

I Want the images to be deleted after the images are shared.

Any help would be appreciated

Below is the onClick of the Share button.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ImageView Imgv = (ImageView)viewPager.findViewWithTag(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            Drawable mDrawable = Imgv.getDrawable();
            Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

            String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
                mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);      

                // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);                 
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                // Launch sharing dialog for image
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share sticker via"));  

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,try this way to delete image

```
File fdlt = new File(file_path);
    if (fdlt .exists()) {
        if (fdlt .delete()) {
            System.out.println("File Deleted :" + file_path);
        } else {
            System.out.println("File not Deleted :" + file_path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My onActivityResult is currently empty.could you please elaborate and tell me how to add this to my onActivityResult ?

Comment: you need use File to set path

Comment: I tried the above method but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Run a Asynctask which will wait for a Time and then it will delete the Image, 
Execute this Asynctask when you will come to your app after sharing that Image.

For This use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent,int)
```

and Override

```
OnActivityResult
```

and Check if you are coming back from sharing the Image with Particular request code and then execute the asynctask. 
It will delete image after a time or you also can delete image immediately on OnActivityResult. 
Hope it Helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and tell me how to do this with reference to my code?